# android layoutview item in listview

Tags: android, listview, events, click, touch

I have faced with very strange behavior in listview android.
I puts several ViewGroups(actually RelativeLayout) into a ListView as
its item. The ViewGroup has TextViews and ImageViews.
I registered OnClickListener on the ImageViews in the ViewGroup.
When I tabbed the ImageViews, The OnClickListener is called in delayed
(It was over than 2 seconds.). Sometimes, the OnClickListener is 
never called unless I tabbed another view in a device.
In that case, the method is called multiply and in burst.

I think it seems to be related to focus. But I can not find a solution.
This strange behavior occurs in only Galaxy S3. It works fine in Galaxy S4.

Meanwhile, OnTouchListener works fine even in the case in Galaxy S3.
It means that a touch event arrives the View in the ViewGroup. I can not
understand why the OnClickListener is called delayed or in out of focus
even it receives touch events in OnTouchListeners.

```
12-27 23:31:51.203: I/debug(19534): myimageview touch event!!!
12-27 23:31:51.268: I/debug(19534): myimageview touch event!!!
12-27 23:31:51.278: I/debug(19534): myimageview touch event!!!
12-27 23:31:51.278: I/debug(19534): myimageview touch event!!!
12-27 23:31:53.333: D/AbsListView(19534): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-27 23:31:53.433: D/AbsListView(19534): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-27 23:31:53.518: I/debug(19534): dofollow clicked!!!222222222222
```

In above log, you can see 4 times touch event. But OnClickListener is
call after 2 seconds from last touch event.

UPDATE:
I did reset my device(GalaxyS3) by tabbing reset button which is shown when
I pressed long a power button of my device. And I tested it again. But,
It was same result. 
However, Today, I powered off my device by seperation of a battery.
And powered on. It works fine without any source code changes!.
Is there any difference between the reset by power-off and software-reset?
Anyway, It words good this time. I will report it again if the
behavior occurs again next time.

UPDATE:
I figure out that this issue is happened in all android devices. I guess
that it is related to drawing cache of ListView. I guess that ListView
makes drawing caches for its child views in sometimes. I checked it out
by enabling showing boundaries of all views in android system setting.
After enabling showing boundaries, I navigates several items in ListView.
Then, I saw some view of child of ListView does not have its child 
layout boundary. It means that it is just image not a view.
In that time, All controls(including ImageView) does not work.
After just little scrolling of the ListView, The queued click events are
flushed to a child control at that time. It means that scrolling of ListView
triggers changing of the cache image with the real view.
I can not find a way turning off this drawing cache in ListView.

UPDATE:
I solved this issue. I feeds views created statically by myself instead of
using convertView in getView method. In this case, something wrong is 
happend inside of ListView. I changed it to use convertView always.

Comment: please post the code of the adapter.I think you've implemented it the wrong way . if you are new to listViews, watch the lecture "the world of listview". onTouchListener is called more than once since it's called even on slightest changes of movements of your finger.

Comment: To 'android developer', the issue is not happened at present. If I face the issue again, I will post the source code in this thread. Thank you.

Comment: so you should check it out on other devices and/or emulators, just to be sure...